# Is it possible to send keystrokes to background window using the InputSimulator API?

Tags: c#, input

I am trying to simulate keypress and text entry to a virtual machine without bringing it to the front, so that I can do my other work, without interruption. I am using the InputSimulator API for Visual Studio.

I've tried using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg);
```

I've tried it with the process name and with the windows name and I can't get it to work.

It would be great if it works, because right now there is no issue in sending keystrokes to the active window, but I can't manage to make it work on a background window.

EDIT:

This is an example of an attempt to use PostMessage.

```
string processName = "myprocessname";
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process P in processList)
{
    if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
    {
        IntPtr myprocess = P.MainWindowHandle;
        PostMessage(myprocess, InputSimulator.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code demonstrating how you are consuming PostMessage? Are you using the Window Handle (hWnd)?

Comment: why dont you just simulate the keystroke in the VM itself?

Comment: `string processName = "myprocessname";
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process P in processList)
    {
        if (P.ProcessName.Equals(processName))
        {
            IntPtr myprocess = P.MainWindowHandle;
            PostMessage(myprocess, InputSimulator.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
          
        }
    } `              

This is an example of an attempt to use PostMessage.

P.S - I can't install or run personal software on the VM.